# JavaScript equal operations anomalies

Tags: javascript, string, operators, equality, equality-operator

I'm working on a lecture about hard to understand JavaScript code and of course on of the weak point of JavaScript is knowing what == / === will return.
I found this great answer in stack that covers this subject nicely -
[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use?answertab=votes#tab-top)

one of the things that caught my eyes (probably because I wasn't aware of it until now) was that you can use String Objects instead of primitives and you will get different result in your conditions -

```
"abc" == new String("abc")    // true
"abc" === new String("abc")   // false
```

I wanted to test it and found out a few not so intuitive results using String Objects -

```
new String("abc") === new String("abc")    // false
```

and even

```
new String("abc") == new String("abc")   // false
```

at the beginning I thought this is a browser bug, but I tested it both on chrome and Firefox. 
So I'd be really happy if some one could share more information how can it be that comparing a literal string and a string object will be truthy but comparing two "equal" string objects will be falsy

Comment: Try this: `console.log(typeof (new String("abc"))); console.log(typeof "abc");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> comparing two "equal" string **objects** will be falsy

I've highlighted the important word above. Two object references are never equal to each other unless they refer to *exactly the same object*.

You're creating two new instances of `String`. That's two separate objects, even if they do have the same string value.

```
var s1 = new String("abc"),
    s2 = new String("abc");

s1 === s1; // true
s1 === s2; // false
```

This is summarised in the spec by the following line in both the [abstract equality algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3) and the [strict equality algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.6):

> Return `true` if *x* and *y* refer to the same object. Otherwise, return `false`.

Comment: im not an expert but shouldn't this: `new String("abc") == new String("abc")` be truthy?

Comment: @x4rf41 - No, for the same reason `{ x: 1 } == { x: 1 }` is not true.

Comment: @x4rf41 I'm betting `"abc" == new String("abc")` is truthy is because since one of the operands is a string, it coerces the other, and in that comparison, they are `==` (which is what I think would lead you to think `new String("abc") == new String("abc")` is truthy, but isn't, since they're both objects)

Comment: @Ian - Exactly. The `==` (abstract equality operator) will cause the coercion of its arguments.

Comment: @JamesAllardice Right, but I was hopefully trying to explain why they might **think** `new String("abc") == new String("abc")` is truthy. They're already the same type, so there's no coercion. In the OP, `"abc" == new String("abc")` is truthy because the object is coerced into the string. I'm just thinking that's why they were confused about this specific case

Comment: JamesAllardice and @Ian good explanation.
I completely missed that since both are Objects they will be compared as Objects